# How to use my chrome extension to trigger a click on another extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome Extension but I am stuck at the point where I want to click another extension in the window .. is it possible to trigger that event that way?

Comment: Probably not. Extensions are sandboxed. I wouldn't your extension accessing my getpocket information, for example, or disabling my VPN, or looking at my Google calendar.

Comment: Chrome doesn't provide a WebExtensions API for interacting with other extensions except for the `management` API which is very limited.